# Parsing with embedded &lt; and &gt;

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I've a HTML content which has HTML entities like `<`, `>`, `%` in the HTML tags.

```
html_text = '<td class="web" width="56" valign="middle" style="color:#333333; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px; padding-top:38px; padding-bottom:40px;"><img alt="<%= ab("###/a/j/img1_alt_text=Hey") %>" src="<%%= @dropbox_path %>/path/to/image/image.png" width="42" height="41" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" style="display:block; vertical-align:top;">String1</td>'
```

When I make HTML doc out of this HTML content(in string)
using

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_text,nil, "UTF-8")
```

and I try to traverse it asking to give me a text node,

html_doc.traverse do |x|

x.text?

temp = x.content

puts temp

I actually wanted here `'String1'` as the output, but it gives me:

```
" src="/path/to/image/image.png" width="42" height="41" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" style="display:block; vertical-align:top;">
```

Comment: *"I try to traverse it asking to give me a text node"* - could you show the corresponding code?

Comment: The <%..%> stuff looks like erb. If so, you could first render the template and then use nokogiri to parse the output.

Comment: This part : alt="<%= ab("###/a/j/img1_alt_text=Hey") %>", uses '"' for nested quotes while the outer quotes uses '"' too. Try changing the inner one to use ' instead of ".

Comment: You could do that on an editor that supports highlighting HTML, easier to see if it's correct or not.

Comment: Unless you show us what CSS selector you're using to access the "text node", we're at a loss to help you. Consider "[GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)".

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
page.css('td')[0].text
```

Refer to "[Parsing HTML with Nokogiri](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/)" for more information.

Comment: `css('td')[0]` is better written as `at('td')` or `at_css('td')`.